# APT Ignoring IPv4 Settings

Tags: networking, apt

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 server and I when I attempt to update, apt is trying to connect to IPV6, thereby ignoring my `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4`, which are as follows:
`Acquire::ForceIPv4 “true”;`...

Does anyone know how I can force the server to only use IPv4?

thanks

Comment: Did you really use `“smart quotes”` - or regular ASCII quotes, like `"true"`?

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for the feedback Doesn't seem to matter, using `Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";` I get the same problem.

Comment: Try a slightly different syntax: `Acquire::ForceIPv4=true;`

Comment: @user535733  that didn't work... but I think I have a different underlying issue... my entire vm seems to have lost connectivity to the outside web...    I need to address that and come back to this issue..

Comment: @user535733  your suggestion works... my firewall was down and wasn't routing traffic... activated the firewall using your solution, I get IPv4 apt downloads... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Scripted approach based on @user in comments:

```
tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4 <<EOF
Acquire::ForceIPv4=true;
EOF
```

[This very old article](https://www.vultr.com/docs/force-apt-get-to-ipv4-or-ipv6-on-ubuntu-or-debian/) suggests using: `Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";` which didn't work for myself or OP so it could be version- or OS-dependent.

I have this in my `Automation_Custom_Script.sh` (which runs as `root`) for my [DietPi](https://dietpi.com/) builds; keep in mind it needs to match `644 root:root`.